# Unity 3D - How to run a piece of code only ...% of the time?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ads

I'm trying to implement interstitial ads in my android app, but I only want it to show an ad like 1/5 (20%) of the time.

Right now I have it set up that every time when I die, it switches scenes to the MenuScene, and on scene load it shows an ad.

I dont want to irritate my users with ads all the time, so that's why I don't want to show it every time they die (because you die a lot in this game ;p).

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Random() class to generate a number between 1 and 100, and if its 1-20, show the ads, otherwise not.

But that would be, as the class suggests, completely random.

Another approach would be a simple counter, so it showed the ads every 5th time you show the MenuScene.
You could save the integer counter in SharedPreferences and simply increment it every time MenuScene is shown, and then only if the counter == 1, show the ads.

This would give a more consistent level.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is pretty much is the answer I was looking for :). I think I'm going for your second approach, but I'm not sure how to make such a timer (I just started coding and using unity). If you'd have any spare time, could you please help me out with that! I would highly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: hi @Bartvb98 - are you still there?  PLEASE tick an answer, to help keep the board tidy, also you get points to ask more questions unmoderated.